# Web Server shows no content

Tags: visual-studio-code

Upon clicking the http-server on my terminal, I get no content on my web-server. I tried:

```
<head>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">

</head>

<body>

    <h1> Hello World </h1>

</body>
```

and my terminal looks like:

> "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
>   (node:10112) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning:
>   OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated

Comment: Is that the source code of you complete html file? Add the missing tags like `<html>` etc. Look e.g. here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp

Comment: @John Archer thanks for your response i did add <!DOCTYPE html> and <html> beginning the code, but didnt seem to show it in my question, its working fine now. If I remember correctly, after clicking the html file in my folder than searching it in the browser, somehow made it work

Comment: @michael rohde So the problem is gone now and all works fine?

Comment: @John Archer Yes. But i have a new problem now i added a button which directs me to a new html page but thats not working. My terminal says:"GET /css/style.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

Comment: @John Archer Sorry im totally new, im following a video and doing everything the same.

Comment: @michael rhode Ok, if you original problem is solved, post an answer (see bottom) so that this topic is "closed". Regarding you other problem: You have added code to link/load the file `style.css` in a folder called `css`. You don't seem to have created the `css` folder and the file `style.css`, which you have to do. EDIT: Can you post the link the the video, please?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3GVXEa_1r8&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hgNu5zXbGctiCWYebxjdeey&index=4

Comment: @michael rohde Did you also watch the videos before that part? In this video you can clearly see the file `ces\style.css` in the project folder, so you seem to miss something.